# Wicket 6.5.0: DefaultTableTree won't expand

Tags: java, wicket

Currently I'm trying to implement a TableTree. But somehow it will not expand the nodes. I did not find anything about how this can happen. My demo-setup contains data which should be rendered as children of my root nodes.

Stepping through the wicket code revealed the node never changes it's state to `EXPANDED`

The root elements are displaying `OrderWrapper`-Entities, which have a Set of `OrderItem`.

Here is the relevant code. If you need any more information I will do my best to provide it.

The Panel containing the TableTree:

```
public class CustomerDetailPanel extends Panel implements CustomerSelecting {

@SpringBean
OrderService orderService;

@SpringBean
OrderWrapperDao orderWrapperDao;

public CustomerDetailPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    init();
}

public CustomerDetailPanel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
    super(id, model);
    init();
}

private List<? extends IColumn<CustomerDetailDto, String>> createColumns() {
    List<IColumn<CustomerDetailDto, String>> result = new LinkedList<>();

    result.add(new TreeColumn<CustomerDetailDto, String>(Model.of("Datum")));

    result.add(new PropertyColumn<CustomerDetailDto, String>(Model
            .of("Amount"), "amount"));

    //more columns...

    return result;
}

private void init() {
    WebMarkupContainer orders;
    Customer c = (Customer) this.getDefaultModelObject();
    if (c != null && c.getId() != null) {
        CustomerDetailProvider providerForCustomer = orderService
                .getProviderForCustomer(c);

        List<? extends IColumn<CustomerDetailDto, String>> columns = createColumns();

        DefaultTableTree<CustomerDetailDto, String> tree = new DefaultTableTree<CustomerDetailDto, String>(
                "orders", columns, providerForCustomer, 20);
        orders = tree;
    } else {
        orders = new WebMarkupContainer("orders");
    }

    add(orders);

}

@Override
public void performStepCustomerSelected(AjaxRequestTarget target,
        Customer customer) {
    // Nothing to do yet
}

}
```

The service generating the ISortableTreeProvider:

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

public class CustomerDetailProvider implements
        ISortableTreeProvider<CustomerDetailDto, String> {

    IModel<Customer> customerModel;

    ISortState<String> sortState;

    public CustomerDetailProvider(Customer customer) {
        this(new DefaultLoadableDetachableModel<>(customerDao, customer));
    }

    public CustomerDetailProvider(IModel<Customer> customerModel) {
        this.customerModel = customerModel;
        sortState = new SingleSortState<String>();
        sortState.setPropertySortOrder("dateofOrderBegin",
                SortOrder.ASCENDING);
        LOG.info("CustomerDetailProvider created");
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        customerModel.detach();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends CustomerDetailDto> getChildren(
            CustomerDetailDto node) {
        List<OrderItem> childrenList = orderItemDao.findByParentId(
                node.getOrderWrapperId()).list();

        return transformItemToDto(childrenList).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends CustomerDetailDto> getRoots() {
        List<OrderWrapper> rootList = orderWrapperDao
                .getForCustomer(customerModel.getObject());

        return transformWrapperToDto(rootList).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ISortState<String> getSortState() {
        return sortState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(CustomerDetailDto node) {
        return node.getOrderWrapperId() != null;
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<CustomerDetailDto> model(final CustomerDetailDto object) {
        return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<CustomerDetailDto>() {

            @Override
            public CustomerDetailDto getObject() {
                return object;
            }
        };
    }

    private List<CustomerDetailDto> transformItemToDto(
            List<OrderItem> childrenList) {
        List<CustomerDetailDto> resultList = new LinkedList<CustomerDetailDto>();

        DateConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter();
        BigDecimalCurrencyConverter currencyConverter = new BigDecimalCurrencyConverter();

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        for (OrderItem orderItem : childrenList) {
            CustomerDetailDto nextElement = new CustomerDetailDto();

            nextElement.setComment("");
            nextElement.setDateOfOrderBegin(dateConverter.convertToString(
                    orderItem.getDateOfCreation(), locale));
            nextElement.setTotalValue(currencyConverter.convertToString(
                    orderItem.getTotalValue(), locale));
            nextElement.setBeerName(orderItem.getBeer().getName());
            nextElement.setAmount(orderItem.getAmount() + "");
            nextElement.setOrderItemId(orderItem.getId());

            resultList.add(nextElement);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    private List<CustomerDetailDto> transformWrapperToDto(
            List<OrderWrapper> rootList) {
        List<CustomerDetailDto> resultList = new LinkedList<CustomerDetailDto>();

        DateConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter();
        BigDecimalCurrencyConverter currencyConverter = new BigDecimalCurrencyConverter();

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        for (OrderWrapper orderWrapper : rootList) {
            CustomerDetailDto nextElement = new CustomerDetailDto();

            nextElement.setComment(orderWrapper.getComment());
            nextElement.setDateOfOrderBegin(dateConverter.convertToString(
                    orderWrapper.getDateOfOrderBegin(), locale));
            nextElement.setOrderWrapperId(orderWrapper.getId());
            nextElement.setTotalValue(currencyConverter.convertToString(
                    orderWrapper.getTotalValue(), locale));
            nextElement.setUserName(orderWrapper.getUser().getUserName());

            resultList.add(nextElement);
        }
        return resultList;
    }

}

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(OrderService.class);

@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

@Autowired
private OrderItemDao orderItemDao;

@Autowired
private OrderWrapperDao orderWrapperDao;

public OrderService() {
}

public CustomerDetailProvider getProviderForCustomer(Customer c) {
    return new CustomerDetailProvider(c);
}

}
```

The DataTransferObject:

```
public class CustomerDetailDto {

private String amount;

private String beerName;

private String comment;

private String dateOfOrderBegin;

private Long orderItemId;

private Long orderWrapperId;

private String totalValue;

private String userName;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof CustomerDetailDto)) {
        return false;
    }
    CustomerDetailDto other = (CustomerDetailDto) obj;
    return other.getOrderItemId() == this.getOrderItemId()
            && other.getOrderWrapperId() == this.getOrderWrapperId();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    if (this.getOrderItemId() != null) {
        return this.getOrderItemId().hashCode();
    }

    if (this.getOrderWrapperId() != null) {
        return this.getOrderWrapperId().hashCode();
    }
    return super.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return dateOfOrderBegin;
}

//Getters and setters...

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help and please excuse my bumpy English.

sam

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after all.
It seems my mistake was to use an `AbstractReadOnlyModel`. After changing the function to

```
@Override
public IModel<CustomerDetailDto> model(final CustomerDetailDto object) {
    return Model.of(object);
}
```

everything works fine. Thanks to everybode who read this post.

Answer (score 0):

Read ITreeProvider#model():

```
Important note: The model must implement {@link Object#equals(Object)} and {@link Object#hashCode()} !
```

Model does this for you, but not so AbstractReadOnlyModel.